# Making the VROM load an image and jump to an address on Nexus One?

Tags: arm, nexus-one, cortex-a8

I want to try experimenting with running low level code my *Nexus One* phone, but I can't find a suitable manual describing how.

As far as I know, the VROM does some initial bootstrapping before jumping to the bootloader which would then unpack and load the Linux kernel. What I want to be able to do is to pass a custom image to the VROM and make it jump to my entry point (*place an image at a specific address and make the CPU jump to it*).

**Is it possible?** And is there any documentation describing the *SoC* used by Nexus One?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Figured it out. It's impossible.**

Nexus One's first stage boot-loader has no facilities for bootstrapping custom code. Has to be done with JTAG.